# OpenTBS Word Document hide table

Tags: php, ms-word, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using TBS to create an MS Word Document from a template in PHP and trying to remove a table depending on a boolean variable.

What I'm trying to do is similar to the following code, but I want to remove a table rather than an object...

```
[onload;block=mc:AlternateContent;when [var.x_delete]=0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using TBS with its plugin OpenTBS.

In MS Word, a table is bounded with the element `<w:tbl>`.

Thus the TBS tag for deleting such a table would be:

```
[onload;block=w:tbl;when [var.x_delete]=0]
```

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is provided with a [synopsis](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/xml_synopsis.html) of the main elements of MS Office and LibreOffice.

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't apprievate table. Cheers

Comment: It's worth noting that the TBS tag should be added to the table itself (rather than before/after the table) and it's necessary to use onshow instead of onload if you want to refer to a merged data value (e.g. from a SQL query).

Comment: You can use `block=tbs:table` instead of `block=w:tbl`. "tbs:table" is an alias and makes the template clearer.